# Is it an abnormal to write function with multiple loop and if else statements in java

Tags: java, function

I am writing java function with such a format : 
I did not finish the function but I think the function has abnormal state, that means it is very difficult for another person to understand this code , am I  right?

```
public static int[] BankAndOrderIndex(int currentBank,int[] banksCoverMoneys,Table<Integer, Integer, List> paymentAmounts,Table<Integer, Integer, List> booleanTable){

    int[] bank_order_pair=new int[2];//index 0 -> bank number | index 1 -> index number of order of list in amounts table 
    int counter=0;
    int[] OtherLargestPayment=new int[2];//index 0 -> bank number | index 1 -> index number of order of list in amounts table
    int second_counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<banksCoverMoneys.length; i++){
        if(i!=currentBank){
            for(int x=0; x<booleanTable.get(i, currentBank).size(); x++){
                if((int)booleanTable.get(i,currentBank).get(x)==0){//if there is an inactive payment order
                    if(banksCoverMoneys[i]-(int)paymentAmounts.get(i,currentBank).get(x)>=0){//if it does not create or enlarge a deficit for its sender
                        if((int)paymentAmounts.get(i,currentBank).get(x)>=Math.abs(banksCoverMoneys[currentBank])){//order whose amount is larger than the current deficit
                            boolean such_payment_order=true;
                            if(counter==0){
                                bank_order_pair[0]=i; bank_order_pair[1]=x;
                                counter++;
                            }
                            else if(counter==1){//to control there is smaller such payment order
                                if((int)paymentAmounts.get(i,currentBank).get(x) < 
                                        (int)paymentAmounts.get(bank_order_pair[0],currentBank).get(bank_order_pair[1])){
                                    bank_order_pair[0]=i; bank_order_pair[1]=x; //gives bank and list index for smallest such payment order
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            boolean such_payment_order=false;
                            if(second_counter==0){
                                OtherLargestPayment[0]=i; OtherLargestPayment[1]=x;
                                second_counter++;
                            }
                            else if(second_counter==1){//to find largest such payment order
                                if(){

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This is off-topic but for the record this code gives me palpitations.

Comment: "It is very difficult for another person to understand this code, am I right?" -- Yes.

Comment: Abnormal as in "doesn't usually happen in reality" - no, unfortunately, it's normal. Maybe it wasn't planned, but it happened.

Comment: just going to throw in that writing multiple variable assignmends into one line doesn´t help the readability either, same for mixing camelcase for variables as `OtherLargestPayment`, or moving away from the java language specification in generell.

Comment: You should spend some time looking at other people's code and see how people split methods out, name variables, etc.  It looks like you've learnt Java syntax, but nobody has taught you how to write nice code

Comment: Here are some basic concepts: If the inside of a for-loop gets too complex, make a function/method out of it. Like process_bank_account(int id);. If you have a lot of nested conditions which are also complex, create short-lived booleans and then go if(boolean_1 && boolean_2 && ...). If you give those booleans descriptive names, you can even omit the comments behind your conditions. Also, start to think in classes - make the whole thing a method of some class, maybe one that is centered around it. Not a good thing to do in any case, though, depends on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this is horrible.

Try and keep methods simple and to the point. A method should really only ever do 1 thing.

For example:

we want to do:

```
given a = 1:<br />
 a + a<br />
 a * a<br />
 return a
```

we could write a function like so:

```
public int doStuff(int a){
  int returnInt = 0;
  returnInt = a + a;
  returnInt = returnInt * a
  return returnInt;
}
```

This function however does two things (it adds numbers and multiplies them). 
We can simplify it by splitting it up in two functions like so:

```
public int addIntegers(int a){
 return a+a;
}

public int multiplyIntegers(int a){
 return a*a;
}
```

we could then achieve the same result by calling:

```
multiplyIntegers(addIntegers(1));
```

I would recommend the following book as it goes into far more detail than I could ever post on StackOverflow: [Clean Code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code) by [Robert C martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin).

**Edit**:
As pointed out in the comments the point of my post isn't too clear.
In the example a create a "massive" function with "lots" of logic (doSomething) and a name which doesn't describe what the actual function does.

I then extract the, albeit simple, logic of this "massive" function and divide it between two well defined and appropriately named functions which make the code more readable as well as more maintainable.

Comment: I'm not at all happy with the example you have given. If you really create such simple functions, you gain absolutely nothing. Instead of a simple operator `a*b` you have a function call `multiply(a,b)` that neither reduces the complexity nor improves the readability of a program. A function should abstract *some* details of a task.

Comment: You wouldn't actually ever use functions like these (and not just because it only uses 1 param and thus is very limited). That is also not the goal of my example. I'm not giving the OP a solution rather a way of thought. The core of my answer addresses the fact that you should separate logic into functions. What that logic may be, and what logic you should extract isn't the point of my post. The example I have opted for is incredibly simple and adresses this fact well imo. it takes a "massive" function with a name which doesn't really describe it's function and extracts it to smaller... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 .... functions with a clear name. Thus making the entire code more readable.

Thanks for the feedback though, I will update the answer to better reflect my initial intentions.